# UICollectionView: UICollectionViewCell object is always null in sizeForItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view that contains different custom cells.

These cells contain different content that varies in size.

The cells are defined in the Storyboard, so no registering needed in code.

All i want to do now is change the size in the delegate method depending on the content:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

id cellAtIndexPath = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSLog(@"The cell: %@", cellAtIndexPath);

...
e.g. calling sizeToFit methods and cumulating the sizes of the cells' subviews
...

}
```

The Method is called as expected for every cell, but cellAtIndexPath always returns NULL, no matter what i tried.
So i am not able to access the cell object at the indexPath or its content view.

Any suggestions why i cannot access the cell object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath` method is called by the collection view's flow layout object. The layout is asking for the size of a cell at a time **before** the cells are added to the collection view. You will have to compute the desired cell size "on your own" and return it.

Comment: Thanks! So, from this perspective it is not possible to set different cell heights depending on the subviews (usually call the sizeToFit to calculate it)?

Is there no possibility to "resize" the cells depending on their content? E.g. for UILabels, you would have to calculate the height by line and textlength. And that would be very inaccurate.

Comment: Right. You may find ways to calculate the cell size if it depends on its content, but you cannot depend on the cell views. (E.g. `NSString` provides methods to get text dimensions.)

Comment: This is silly and unfortunate... Doesn't `UITableView` go to the data source and get the cell if you ask it for a cell that doesn't exist yet?